# Rails 7 - autoloading fails for Rails engine RSpec tests with gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, autoload

I maintain https://rubygems.org/gems/scimitar. Yesterday, we wanted to upgrade our primary application to Rails 7. This required a corresponding upgrade of Scimitar.

Tests I think are quite straightforward for a Rails engine; you have a dummy Rails app inside your tests, which `require`s the *gem* code as usual (`require 'scimitar'` in `application.rb`, in this case) and then - well - I guess via the `mount` in the dummy app's `routes.rb`, or some other autoloading magic, it thereafter "just works". Classes that are defined in the *engine's* application components (e.g. `/app/models/gemname/foo.rb` -> `Gemmname::Foo`) are autoloaded and available in your dummy application (e.g. `/spec/dummy/app/controllers/some_controller.rb` can reference `Gemname::Foo`).

The test suite works fine in Rails 6. If I change the `gemspec` file to reference Rails 7 and `bundle update`, tests immediately all fail. None of the constants defined in the engine are visible to the dummy app and since they're referenced by a configuration file  in `spec/dummy/app/config/initializers/scimitar.rb`, the dummy app can't even complete Ruby parsing without raising `NameError` (uninitialized constant). I also ran a Rails 7 upgrade on that dummy app, but it does kinda nothing and had almost no changes; there were no changes to observed behaviour (tests still failed) and the post-upgrade dummy app ran tests successfully with the gem on Rails 6.

So, it just fails to behave in a recognisably sensible way on Rails 7.

Ruby version is unchanged at 2.7.x (though I would have bump to 3.1 if the Rails 7 update had worked).

I cannot find anything about this in 6->7 upgrade docs; classic autoloader has never been used and there is no specification about it either way; `config.load_defaults` as 6.0 or 7.0 makes no difference at all; I tried creating a new engine plugin under Rails 7 to play spot-the-difference, but couldn't see what might be wrong and it was obfuscated somewhat since I'm using RSpec but the out-of-box template uses Minitest.

Can anyone please help explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands in Rails 7.0.1, I found no solution so had to hack around it. Anyone using the Scimitar gem would need to wrap their initializer code (`config/initializers/scimitar.rb`) with:

```rb
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  ...
end
```

- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Reloader.html#method-c-to_prepare

Doing this inside the Gem's own engine initializer code *and* the dummy app initializer code allowed the test suite to run. Likewise, there were quite a few places in our main Rails application beyond just Scimitar that suddenly required this workaround, including some examples of just plain old Ruby gems.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I am suffering from the same issue when running rspec with a gem that doesn't use an initializer. Have you made any more findings on this problem since January?

Comment: The new "to prepare" workaround just seems to be something Rails 7 forces upon us. I released a Rails 7 branch of Scimitar that included the alteration in its template out-of-box initializer some time ago. Without knowing the name of the gem to which you refer or what exactly is the nature of the error your seeing, there's no way to help more. If you posted full details as a StackOverflow question and add a comment here (with the link to the question) so that I get notified, I'll see if I can figure anything out to help.

Comment: I'm having a similar situation. I just upgraded the parent/host application to Rails 7, and now its complaining that certain constants, mostly everything in the Engine's initiaizers folder, are not defined. How did your use the `to_prepare` method in you parent/host app?

Comment: @John exactly as described in the answer to which these comments are attached, basically. If a failing initializer has "Foo.something" inside it, then move that code inside the "to_prepare" block instead - that is, each affected initializer file gets the 'to prepare' call added, wrapping the existing file content. Every app is different and if you're using Engines then that's another story, but it's not something that can be answered in the space of a comment here so if you're stuck, perhaps describe the situation in new StackOverflow question and comment back here with a link to it.